# Compile directly to /Applications from Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, jailbreak

First off, I am not publishing this app to the app store and this is a jailbroken phone.

Anyone know how to compile apps directly to the /Applications folder with Xcode?  Currently, I am having to compile to the /var/mobile/Applications folder and copying it to the /Applications folder on the device.  It would be very convenient if the app could be compiled directly to the /Applications folder.  Google doesn't seem to have any results on this topic.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a jailbroken iPhone, so I can't say if this works, but presuming you can **mount** the iPhone as a volume on the Mac, you can add a custom script to the compilation in Xcode that does the copying for you.

Presuming that your iPhone is mounted in /mnt/My iPhone

You would add a custom build phase (Editor > Add Build Phase > Add Run Script Phase) and the script would do something like:

```
cd /var/mobile/Applications
cp myappfile "/mnt/My iPhone/Applications/"
```

Answer (score 0):

If XCode compiles applications into the same target directory every time, could you put in a [symlink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) to point to your mounted phone? The OS X docs are in the `ln(1)` manpage, look for `-s` for details on symlinks.

e.g., remove `/var/mobile/Applications/`, and replace it with a symlink to wherever your phone's `/Applications/` directory is, (I'm guessing `/Volumes/WakePhone/Applications/`):

```
rmdir /var/mobile/Applications
ln -s /Volumes/WakePhone/Applications/ /var/mobile/Applications
```

Of course, this will only let you compile when your phone is mounted. This might be too much hassle.

Why is copying over your application so onerous that you want to compile directly onto the device? There is probably a better solution than this. :)

Comment: Interesting...the need for compiling directly to /Applications will eliminate a lot of tedious work when debugging apps which need root access (jailbroken).  Thanks for the info, but I still need /var/mobile/Applications to remain on the phone.